# Замена одного значения в строке массивом значений

Tags: php

Есть строка:

$expected = "Отправьте документы по ссылке https://lll.ru/:uniqueString. Всего хорошего [https://lll.ru/:uniqueString.";](https://lll.ru/:uniqueString.%22;)

Есть массив со значениями: $arr = ['aaa', 'bbb'];

Нужно заменить все ":uniqueString" на значения из массива по порядку.

Результат:

$expected = "Отправьте документы по ссылке https://lll.ru/aaa. Всего хорошего [https://lll.ru/bbb.";](https://lll.ru/bbb.%22;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$expected = "Отправьте документы по ссылке https://lll.ru/:uniqueString. Всего хорошего https://lll.ru/:uniqueString.";
$arr = ['aaa', 'bbb'];
$res = vsprintf(str_replace(':uniqueString', '%s', $expected), $arr);
echo $res;
```

Comment: Супер, полезная функция, спасибо.